# channel.consume not working _ rabbitmq Nodejs

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

Im trying to consume some message with rabbitmq in my nodejs server. but my problem is:

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

function init(trackingParam) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function (error0, connection) {
            if (error0) rej(error0)

            connection.createChannel((error1, channel) => {
                if (error1) rej(error1)


                channel.assertExchange(trackingParam, 'fanout', {
                    durable: true
                })

                channel.assertQueue(trackingParam, {
                    durable: false
                })
                channel.bindQueue(trackingParam, trackingParam, '')

                channel.prefetch(1)

                res(channel, trackingParam)
            })
        });
    })
}
function consumeNewMessages(trackingParam, channel) {
    channel.consume(trackingParam, async (msg) => {
        console.log("====================", msg.content.toString());
    }, {
        noAck: false
    })
}


init(trackingParam).then((channel, trackingParam) => {
    consumeNewMessages(channel, trackingParam)
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

my channel doesn't have any consume() function. and even printing my channel. there is no consume() in that. only an object with **consumer :{}** .

Comment: Try removing the package and installing it again... this looks very strange..

Comment: Perhaps you need to change the order of variables from function consumeNewMessages(trackingParam, channel)  to function consumeNewMessages(channel, trackingParam) in the declaration...